# UIImageView initWithImage:self.image shows up as null

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm stumped on this one.  I'm using an image file that was transferred over and is in the classes public properties.  The log file shows me that self.image and newImage are still pointing to the UIImage file.  However, no matter how I setup initWithImage the value of self.imageView.image ends up being (null).

Note : imageView is a private class property that is synthesized.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=self.image.size};
    UIImage *newImage = self.image;
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];

    [self.imageView setFrame: (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=self.image.size}];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image.size;


NSLog(@"Image in self.image : %@ Image for imageView %@ and new Image is : %@", self.image, self.imageView.image, newImage);
```

Where the self.image comes from from the first view controller:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:
(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType =
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
{
    self.imageToBePassed = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(){
        AngleMeasureViewController *angleMeasureViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AngleMeasureViewController"];
        angleMeasureViewController.delegate = (id)self;
        angleMeasureViewController.image = self.imageToBePassed;

        NSLog(@"image passed to Angle Measure View Controller : %@", angleMeasureViewController.image);

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:angleMeasureViewController animated:YES];
    }];


}
```

how it's declared synthesized in the next view controller:

in the header file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image;
```

in the .m

```
@implementation AngleMeasureViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize image = _image;
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting the image property of the UIImageview after initialising it?

Comment: How and where do you get the image for self.image. Please show the actual log that you get.

Comment: Thank you for your responses @Sparq - Yes, I have it's still null.

Comment: @rdelmar updated to include the source of referred to self.image.  I don't have the log data as I've moved in a different direction for the time being after spending way too long on this.  I can say that the reference is pointing to the same spot in memory throughout until it's used in initWithImage:self.image and then imageView.image  is (NULL).